# Chrome extension: when is activeTab permission required

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have read through Chrome extension documentation to understand when the activeTab permission is required and arrived at the conclusion that my Chrome extension will require activeTab permission. To my surprise, the behaviour is no different even when I remove activeTab permission from the manifest i.e it all works fine even when I don't include activeTab permission in my manifest. My code code includes below action on the tabs. Does this not warrant activeTab permission?

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
   .....
});

chrome.tabs.create({url: '/logdisplay.html'}, (tab) => {
   ....
})
```

Comment: This code doesn't need activeTab permission. You would need it only if your query() callback wanted to access `url` property inside the `tabs` array items (but not if manifest.json already requests this host e.g. via `<all_urls>`). I'd say the word "access" in the documentation has confused you. Access means injection via executeScript, reading sensitive info like url, capturing screenshots of the tab etc.

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarification.